# autocomplete won't show dropdown list

Tags: android, database, autocomplete

I used autocomplete and when database was small, it's worked fine, but when database grew, dropdown of autocomplete won't work (not show). For more certainty, in custom adapter, in "FilterResults performFiltering" where make "suggestions", I write an if that "if suggestion size be 1 then break for" and it's worked. but i need to search all database's rows. below is some part of my code:

```
private Filter FieldFilter = new Filter(){
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        List<ModelCategory> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
            suggestions.addAll(FieldListFull);
        } else {
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for(ModelCategory item : FieldListFull) {
                if (item.getNaqsh_jelo().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    suggestions.add(item);
                    if (suggestions.size() == 1{
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = suggestions;
        results.count = suggestions.size();
        return results;
    }
```

if I don't write "if that check suggestion size", the 3 line below

```
results.values = suggestions;
        results.count = suggestions.size();
        return results;
```

won't run!!!! actualy, middle of for loop, FilterResult function without error stop running and PublishResult run, then in publishResult say "result is null"!
below is my PublishResult function:

```
        @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        clear();
        try {
            addAll((List) results.values);

        }catch (Exception e){}
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: When will you get values from service for auto-complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem!
This problem was happening because of null field in DataBase!
the "for loop" of FilterResult function changed like below

```
            for(ModelCategory item : FieldListFull) {
                try{
                    if (item.getNaqsh_jelo().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern) && item.getNaqsh_jelo() != null){
                        suggestions.add(item);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
```